# Tensorflow GAN No gradients provided for any variable

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to build a LSTM-GAN in tensorflow.

Only in the descriminator net, when I try to calculate the loss i get the error

`ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables ["<tf.Variable 'd_w:0' shape=(128, 1) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'd_b:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>"] and loss Tensor("Neg:0", shape=(), dtype=float32).`

the descriminator net looks like this

```
## Descriminator net
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, time_steps, num_inputs], name='x')
d_w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_units,1]), name='d_w')
d_b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]), name='d_b')

des_vars = [d_w, d_b]

def descriminator(x):
    inp = tf.unstack(x, time_steps, 1)
    lstm_layer = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units,forget_bias=1, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)
    outputs, _ = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_layer, inp, dtype='float32')
    descriminator_logit = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(outputs[-1],g_w)+g_b)

    return descriminator_logit

g_prediction = generator(Z)
d_real = descriminator(x)
d_fake = descriminator(Y)


d_loss = -tf.reduce_mean( tf.log(d_real) + tf.log(1. - d_fake) )
g_loss = -tf.reduce_mean( tf.log(d_fake) )

g_optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(g_loss, var_list=gen_vars)
d_optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(d_loss, var_list=des_vars)
```

I'm not sure which part of this is breaking it.. I was thinking it could be the d_fake Variavle. `Y` is a `tf.placeholder` with the same shape as x but is reformatted so it takes the output of the generator net (this is done inside the `tf.session()`

any idea why this is breaking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables in `des_vars` are not being used by `g_loss` and `d_loss`. Your `descriminator` function uses `g_w` and `g_b` but not `d_w` or `d_b`.

You can see which ops depend on which variables very easily by using the [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/graph_viz). Would you have used it in this case, you would have seen that `d_w` and `d_b` were disconnected from the `d_loss` and `g_loss` ops in the graph.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been racking my head against this all day haha I tried using tensorboard but the file would log it because it wasn't making it to the `sess.run` where the graph was being written to tensorboard